# How to stop all cassini instances?

Tags: asp.net, cassini

When I am running my application, It opens many instance of cassini.
How can i stop all or some of the cassini instances quickly.

I know to kill all the processes from task manager.
Can it be done in some better and faster way?

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not this applies to your particular problem, but are you aware that you can turn off "Auto assign port" in project properties, and always use a specific port, if that's what's causing your several instances?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I mean through command in command prompt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The process name has changed on this version its now:

```
taskkill /IM WebDev.WebServer40.exe /F
```

When that doesn't work, check the tasklist for a similar name.

Answer (score 5):

[This Visual Studio extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1269c9a1-fcfe-4b47-91e7-22c7027f3c41) provides a quick way to kill all instances of Cassini (via a shortcut key)

**EDIT :**
If you want to do it via command line only, then you can use the `taskkill` command. An example:

```
taskkill /IM WebDev.WebServer /F
```

See [this page](http://tweaks.com/windows/39559/kill-processes-from-command-prompt/) for more examples, and an explination of the command. You may need to specify WebDev.WebServer40 for the .Net 4 web server

Comment: I had to Add .exe to the end of name, then it works just fine